# What is the least effort way to hard code a large amount of fixed data into source code of an embedded C program?

Tags: c, testing

We have a recurring use case:

- we have a large amount of fixed, unchanging data that needs to be used in a bare metal (no OS) program for verification of the silicon we are taping out.
- because it is bare metal, we have no file system
- We are just doing #defines right now, manually entering the data into the source code
- there is a *lot* of data
- this is verification, so there are no code style concerns.  We just need the least (human programming) effort way to get the data into a binary so that the binary can put it into DRAM during an automated test run

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: generate header file using your favourite scripting tool and include that header into your code

Comment: It depends on several things but for starters: Where do you have all "fixed data" from? Are they available in files from the "silicon development process"? If so simply write a little program/script that extracts the data and put the data into a C-file.

Comment: What does the source data look like, is it available in a file?  Write code (in your language of choice) to generate the C code your target needs.  It is too obvious for an answer, and without knowing the data format, and content and the nature of the generated code, or what language you would use for generation it is not really possible to post a useful answer.  It seems that a great deal of #define may not be appropriate, an const array or struct may be more appropriate - hard to tell without more detail.

Comment: C23 `#embed`, someday.

Comment: Your question does not state what form the data is in initially. Is it a raw binary file? A text list of numbers? A CSV file?

Comment: On macOS, `xxd -i <File>` generates C code to define an `unsigned char` array with the data in `<File>`. It is a simple program to write.

Answer (score 0):

Use a table. A static global table that you generate by a program at build time. That’s one way. Probably this will give you more ideas on how to proceed.